# How to not delete a copy of base class object?

Tags: c++

My problem is, that when I'm using inheritance class, my base class is deleting 2 times (the copy from inheritance too). Is there a chance to not make a copy of base class? Or not delete it?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class base {
public:
    base() { cout << "*B"; }
    ~base() { cout << "~B"; }
};

class restaurant : virtual public base {};

int main() {
    base* d1 = new base;
    restaurant restaurant;
    delete d1;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `*B*B~B~B` but I would like to have `*B*B~B` because I'm not deleting restaurant, only base object.

Comment: The object is deleted during exiting main..

Comment: But you do delete `restaurant` here ---> `return 0;`. All local variables are destroyed when function exists it's scope.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how the object lifetimes work... Your "restaurant" object is still deleted when it goes out of scope, that is where your second "~B" comes from.

Comment: I see, so there is no chance to not displaying it in console? Actually it is ok, when it is deleting, but I would like not to display it in console...

Comment: and you are missing a virtual destructor in your base class. It will leak when you will try a `base* b = new restaurant,` even if you call `delete b;`

Comment: @Moia "It will leak" - It will be undefined behavior. Leaking is just one possible effect.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen No, but undefined behavior might include leaking memory. Deleting through a base pointer without a virtual destructor is UB.

Comment: @SebastianRedl My bad, didn't read your comment carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not `delete`ing `restaurant`, but you didn't `new` it either; it's allocated in automatic storage ("the stack"), not dynamic storage ("the heap"). Objects in automatic storage have their destructor called when they go out of scope. This is why the `restaurant` destructor is still being called in this case.

If you'd written:

```
restaurant *restaurant = new restaurant;
```

you'd see the behaviour you're expecting. Of course, by calling `new` without a matching `delete` you will be leaking the object, so this is not recommended.

Comment: It's better to use words like *"automatic storage"* than *"the stack"* in this context.

Comment: @SergeyA It certainly doesn't hurt to mention both terms, thanks.

Comment: Ok, I did what you said and it is working, thank You.

Comment: @VidelIchinose if you're not deleting, you have a memory leak. Try not doing that

Comment: I'm downvoting this answer. It proposes leaking an object, which is generally a bad idea, and not even explaining that it is a bad idea and why.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I assumed that the question was just academic, but recent comments suggest otherwise... yikes.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, objects with automatic storage are automatically deleted a the end of a scope. So declaring `restaurant restaurant;` will construct a restaurant but will also delete it automatically at the end of the `main` function.

Try this:

```
struct A {
    A() { std::cout << "A()"; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "~A()"; }
};

struct B : A {
    B() { std::cout << "B()"; }
    ~B() { std::cout << "~B()"; }
};

auto main() -> int {
    B b;
} // b destroyed here
```

[The output is](https://godbolt.org/z/0xmkpC):

> ```
> A()B()~B()~A()
> ```

It behave like a stack. First, the base class is constructed, then the derived class. Then, it destroy the derived first and the base class at the end.

This behaviour is extremely important for most C++ idiom.

Consider this:

```
struct A {
    A() : arr(new int[3]{1, 2, 3}) {}
    ~A() { delete[] arr; }
    int* arr = nullptr;
};

struct B : A {
    B() {}
    ~B() {}
    auto stuff() -> int {
        return std::accumulate(arr, arr + 3, 0);
    }
};

auto main() -> int {
    B b;
    return b.stuff(); // returns 1 + 2 + 3
}
```

What would happen if the constructor `A()` was not executed first? The array would be null. That would be bad.

Also... what would happen if the destructor `~A()` was not executed? That would be a *memory leak*. That would be super bad.

Constructors and destructors have a guaranteed execution and a well defined order. This is why you don't have to call `super()` and `~super()` in all of you constructors and destructor. Because you could forget to call it. Destructor and constructor is not something you want to forget to call, or else there would be no advantages over just using free function like in C.

Comment: Kind of irrelevant to your answer, but why would anyone prefer `auto main() -> int ` over `int main()` ? This makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen consistency. Sometime you don't have a choice to use trailing return types. I prefer to use it everywhere and have all my function names aligned as opposed as in some places. Same thing for `using` vs `typedef`, etc.

Comment: I would really like to have a `func` keyword to replace the `auto` at the begining.

Answer (score 0):

The output is expected output.
I have added comments in your main function code.

```
int main() {

    //Create base class object and constructor will be called
    //This object is allocated on heap
    base* d1 = new base;

    //Create derived class object
    //first constructor of base and then derived (if defined) will be called 
    //This object is allocated on stack
    restaurant restaurant;

    //Free memory and Call destructor of base class object
    delete d1;

    return 0;

    //After bracket, stack object will go out of scope and destructor will be called.
    //First derived (if defined) class destructor and then base class destructor.
}
```

To get expected output : `*B*B~B`

```
restaurant *restaurant = new restaurant;
```

But if you don't delete it then it will create memory leak in your program.